# How to load Keras models with proper Session and Graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I have 2 Keras models saved as `.pkl` file, I am loading both of them sequentially like below.

```
model1 = pickle.loads("../model1.pkl")
model2 = pickle.loads("../model2.pkl")
```

My question is does both of the models are loaded in

- Same global session and 2 different sub-graphs.  (or)
- Individual sessions and corresponding graphs.(Example: session1-graph1-model1, session2-graph2-model2).